# Database migration, read constraint

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to migrate a database in yii2. I want to read from MySQL database values for foreign key constraints,  on delete cascade, restrict, set null. The same for on update values. Is it some possiblities to do it in migration tool. I use this tool: https://github.com/mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getSchema()->getTableSchema('table_name')->foreignKeys` on your DB connection.